# Laravel can't update data MySQL

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, controller

Everything shows up right in dd but nothing changed in table. Does anyone know why?

```
$name = $request->get('name');
$now= new DateTime;
$userId = Auth::id();

dd($name . $userId); //tady je to ještě OK

DB::table('users')->where('id', $userId)->where('changed_name', '<', Carbon::now()->subdays(60)->toDateTimeString())->update(['name' => $name, 'changed_name' => $now]);

return redirect('/profile');
```

Comment: you're comparing `changed_name` with `Carbon::now()->subdays(60)->toDateTimeString()` it should be `$name` as I assume. It might be different as your point of view.

Comment: @DilipHirapara it could be that `changed_name` is the date they changed their name.

Comment: changed_name is timestamp, you should be able to change name only once per 60 days

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that name and `changed_name` are in `$fillable array` in `users` model.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$name = $request->get('name');
$now= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$userId = Auth::id();
dd($name . $userId); //tady je to ještě OK
DB::table('users')->where('id', $userId)->where('changed_name', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30 days')))->update(['name' => $name, 'changed_name' => $now]);
OR
DB::table('users')->where('id', $userId)->where('changed_name', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 month')))->update(['name' => $name, 'changed_name' => $now]);

return redirect('/profile');
```

Make sure that these fields are fillable in model.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that `changed_name` are in `$fillable` array in `users` model.
2. Match the format of `changed_name` with getting your now time